# Merge values under same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [Example] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1,2,3,4 
        [1] => 2,4,5,6,7
    ) 
)
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
Array ( 
    [Example] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    ) 
)
```

So all under one key, and duplicates removed.

**EDIT** - here's the actual code I'm working with.

I have a list of settings in WordPress where users can choose their Google font, and the variants to go with that font.

I have an array of settings, which I'm looping through:

```
$options = array(
    'first_option',
    'second_option',
);

$font_families = array();
$font_variants = array();

foreach ( $options as $key ) {
    $value = get_theme_mod( $key );

    if ( ! in_array( $value, $font_families ) ) {
        $font_families[$value] = $value;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $font_variants[$value] ) ) {
        $font_variants[$value] = array();
    }

    $font_variants[$value] = get_theme_mod( $key . '_variant' );
}

print_r( $font_families );
// Array ( [Open+Sans] => Open+Sans [Amiri] => Amiri )

print_r( $font_variants );
// Array ( [Open+Sans] => Array ( [0] => 300,regular,italic,700 [1] => 300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic ) [Amiri] => Array ( [0] => regular,italic,700,700italic ) )
// The above is where the issue comes in, I need to merge [0] and [1] inside the same array.
```

Now with these values, I can build my URL to request the fonts from Google:

```
foreach ( $font_families as $font_family ) {
    $google_fonts[] = $font_family . ':' . implode( ',', $font_variants[$font_family] );
}

$google_fonts = implode( '|', $google_fonts );
$font_args[ 'family' ] = $google_fonts;

$fonts_url = add_query_arg( $font_args, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );

print_r( $font_url );
// https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,regular,italic,700,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic|Amiri:regular,italic,700,700italic
```

The problem is in the Open Sans call - we're calling various variants twice, when we only need to call them once.

Comment: Think about this in parts. You need to combine the strings into one, convert that into an array, remove duplicates, then convert back into a string. [Example here](https://eval.in/private/968238f44d8ee4)

Comment: @DaveChen That worked perfectly: `$font_variants[ $font_family ] = implode( ',', array_unique( explode( ',', implode( ',', $font_variants[$font_family] ) ) ) );`

It feels so messy though. Maybe my starting point (I've added examples above) is all wrong. I'll keep playing with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) and [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4]
$array2 = [2,4,5,6,7];
$result = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which removes duplicate keys.

As your example appears to utilise strings to store your numbers, you're also looking to **[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** them on the comma:

```
<?php

$string1 = "1, 2, 3, 4";
$string2 = "2, 4, 5, 6, 7";

$array1 = explode(",", $string1);
$array2 = explode(",", $string2);

print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));

/* Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 2 [5] => 4 [6] => 5 [7] => 6 [8] => 7 ) */

?>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `SORT_REGULAR` way is good one to merge and remove duplicates. You can try this way also, See demo here https://eval.in/840895

```
$array =[ 
    'Example' => [ 
        [1,2,3,4], 
        [2,4,5,6,7]
    ]
];

$result['Example'][0] = implode(',',array_unique(array_merge(... $array['Example'])));
print '<pre>';
print_r($result );
print '</pre>';
```